# java - Check if a thread is interrupted without a loop or Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to call an external method which sometimes takes indefinite time to complete.

```
void doMyStuff(){
  // do my stuff
  // work is being done by doStuff thread
  externalMethod(); // This is external and sometimes takes hours
  // I need to check if current thread is interrupted and then return after a certain time 
}
```

However, I can't afford to keep a thread engaged, so I need to terminate the process after a fixed time. I can interrupt the doStuff thread from an external thread with the help of [Websphere's WorkManager API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/WorkManager.html). But only sending the interrupt signal is useless unless the interrupted thread handles it.

I want to return the doStuff thread to thread pool after a certain time no matter whether the `extenalMethod()` returns or not. How can this be done?

Comment: You could also a handy lib like this: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `myThread.isInterrupted()` to see if the Thread is interrupted or not.

```
void doMyStuffs(){
    //do my stuffs
    System.out.println(myThread.isInterrupted());
}
```

Comment: writing this before `extenalMethod()` is useless and if it  is written after `externalMethod()` it will never be called unless `externalMethod()` returns.

Comment: @Frank **Don't** use `myThread.stop()`: ["This method is inherently unsafe"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()).

Comment: @ares so... you want to check in the middle of `externalMethod()`? Well, you need to add the check to `externalMethod()`.You can't stop `externalMethod` doing anything unless it checks for interruptions already.

Comment: @ares You can't write this at the end of your stuffs?

Comment: @AndyTurner: That would be ideal but as the name suggests, it's managed by an external entity and can't changed.

Comment: @ares this is just the nature of cooperative interruption. If the code you are running doesn't cooperate, you can't do anything about it.